# how can I access multi variable return in another function in code igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

### How can I access multi variable return in another function code igniter?

**my code like this :**

```
function extract_fitur($string, $judul){

    $data_total_kalimat=array();
    $data_kalimat=array();
    $data_posisi_kalimat=array();
    $data_kata3=array();
    foreach ($string as $key => $value) {
        $kalimat=$value;
        $total_kalimat=count($value);
        $data_posisi=array();
        $data_kata2=array();

        foreach ($value as $key2 =>$value2) {
            $data_kata=array();
            $pecah_kata=explode(" ", $value2);  
            foreach ($pecah_kata as $key3 => $value3) {
                array_push($data_kata, $value3);

            }
            array_push($data_kata2, $data_kata);
            array_push($data_posisi, $key2);
        }

            array_push($data_kata3, $data_kata2);
            array_push($data_posisi_kalimat, $data_posisi);
            array_push($data_total_kalimat, $total_kalimat);
            array_push($data_kalimat, $kalimat);
    }
}
```

I want to access variable $data_3, $data_posisi_kalimat, $data_total_kalimat, $data_kalimat in another function.
**example my function:**

```
function access_my_var(){
// I want to access all variable in above;
}
```

Comment: If you're needing to do this, then you've designed your code incorrectly.

Comment: return array($data1,data2....);  and call the function like this  function access_my_var(){
 $all_variable_array = extract_fitur($string, $judul);
}

Comment: but how I can access just one or more variable? like I just access variable $data_kata3 or another else @JYoThI

Comment: if you want access the variable anywhere means make it as a global variable .@Rachmad

Comment: oh..yes, thanks for your solution. I will try it now

Comment: try and let me know @Rachmad

Comment: Sory @JYoThI I don't make it to global variabel, I just accest like this, `   return array($data_kata3,
    $data_posisi_kalimat,
    $data_total_kalimat,
    $data_kalimat, $judul);` like your code.

Comment: you want access the same variable with same name is it ? @Rachmad

Comment: no, I mean I just want to access all variable in another function. cz I need some variable in some function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

1. use PHP `explode` function to break the string into sentences.
2. in the second `foreach` loop, split the sentence using PHP `str_split`
3. combine all the array into single variable

   ```
   public function extract_fitur($string, $judul)
   {
       $data_total_kalimat=array();
       $data_kalimat=array();
       $data_posisi_kalimat=array();
       $data_kata3=array();

       $array_string = explode(". ", $string);
       foreach ($array_string as $key => $value) {
           $kalimat=$value;
           $total_kalimat=count($value);
           $data_posisi=array();
           $data_kata2=array();

           foreach (str_split($value) as $key2 =>$value2) {
               $data_kata=array();
               $pecah_kata=explode(" ", $value2);  
               foreach ($pecah_kata as $key3 => $value3) {
                   array_push($data_kata, $value3);

               }
               array_push($data_kata2, $data_kata);
               array_push($data_posisi, $key2);
           }

           array_push($data_kata3, $data_kata2);
           array_push($data_posisi_kalimat, $data_posisi);
           array_push($data_total_kalimat, $total_kalimat);
           array_push($data_kalimat, $kalimat);
       }

       $return_variable = array();
       $return_variable['data_total_kalimat'] = $data_total_kalimat;
       $return_variable['data_kalimat'] = $data_kalimat;
       $return_variable['data_posisi_kalimat'] = $data_posisi_kalimat;
       return $return_variable;
   }
   ```

Comment: you're welcome.. you can go through the guide in https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/index.html - have a nice day. :)